# I have raised a pull request and it is showing there "2 workflows awaiting approval ". Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Tags: git, github

I am a fresher in open source and I yesterday solved one issue and apply the pull request .But till now there is no reply from the organization. Now what can i do  to resolve this?

I was trying to apply pull request and expecting that it will be merge with original repository?

Comment: As it's a public project it's perfectly safe to show us the URL of the PR. Also please be warned that free software/open source developers are usually quite busy (life, job, other projects) and don't answer for weeks, may be for months, alas.